# Change ipaddress of a node on open source chef server

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

I have been experimenting with open source chef server. I configured a node on my server which had ip address 10.114.7.41. Now when I restarted the node machine and now the ip address of the machine has changed to 10.114.7.45. But the chef server still has the ip address of this node as the previous one which can be checked by:

```
knife search 'node:name'
```

How can I rectify this from my workstation/chef-server? I am not able to 'knife ssh' the node machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can access the node and re-run chef-client, it should pick up the new IP address and change it for you. Ohai runs at the beginning of each chef-client run and collects this data and updates the chef server.

Comment: I know but this requires chef-client to be run manually or by ssh on the new ip address. But my questions is how can it be managed by workstation or directly changing it from chef server.

Comment: The chef-client has to run in order to change automatic attributes set by Ohai. You can't edit that value manually.

Comment: Does this mean in a DHCP environment chef is not a good choice for provisioning?

Comment: No, chef is fine for provisioning in a DHCP environment. Are you re-assigning IPs routinely? Typically, you have your IP address assigned before you can even bootstrap, so I'm not sure what configuration you are using. If your IP address is changing after the initial provisioning with Chef, you will have to re-run chef-client to update the node object with the new information.

Comment: Apart from running the chef client as cron job, can I rectify the issue from workstation?

Comment: You could execute a `knife node edit nodename -a` which would let you edit all attributes on the node object by hand. I don't really recommend this though as it's always easy to accidentally make typos.

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution is `-m` with the knife invocation?

```
knife ssh -m host.dhcp.net -- chef-client
```

.. always seemed a little gauche.